# cordova-plugin-device prevents deviceready from firing

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am working on an app which was working well until I pushed my latest update, and I have traced it to be an issue with cordova-plugin-device.

I get the errors

```
cordova.js:1223 deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
cordova.js:1216 Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady
```

after adding the plugin `cordova-plugin-device`.

This happens even for a simple hello world app I get from running this in the cordova project directory

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

with the only difference being the addition of the plugin via (in the project directory)

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
```

**Possible Causes**

I have explored the different possibilities that may have caused the issue, but none of them has solved the problem.

1. Content-Security-Policy

I have changed the meta-tag in my `index.html` page to

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
```

to no avail.

2. Install newest plugin/platform

It did not work. The following are the versions I am working with:

```
$ npm --version
4.2.0
$ cordova -v     
6.5.0
$ cordova platforms
Installed platforms:
android 6.1.2
$ cordova plugins     
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
```

I suspect it is a bug in `cordova-plugin-device` itself. Appreciate opinions if I should file a bug report.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you added the browser platform?  I followed your steps in your post, and only added "browser" and it's all good.  I think the issue is that since you don't have browser added, it doesn't generate cordova.js for the "parent" folders.  If you have android/ios/win platforms installed, you will have a cordova.js in that specific platform.  If you do a "cordova platform add browser" it will start generating the cordova.js in the root project

Comment: I have just tried adding and serving browser, and the problem still persists. I did not encounter any problem with the cordova.js file when running cordova serve android or cordova serve browser.

Anyway if it works for you, I might try reinstalling cordova entirely. I see this same problem popping up all over the internet, but have never found a definitive solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm on 6.1.1, let me upgrade and see.  The bug possibility chances increase!

Comment: Ok on 6.5.0, it is still working for me.  I had to navigate to platforms/browser/www, and copy cordova.js from there, and paste it in root/www, but I'm getting device ready.  Double checked to make sure plugins are installed: cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist" ... I think I have basically the same setup as you now.

Comment: Thanks, I have downgraded to 6.1.1 and still no luck. I wonder what the difference could be...

Comment: What npm are you on? 4.1.2 here.  Not that I particularly think that would be the issue, but if we're on the same setup otherwise, it's something else to check.

Comment: `$ npm -v

3.5.2`

Looks outdated... I'll try upgrading it.

Comment: hm... tried everything, from reinstalling npm and the android platform. Versions are now
npm 4.2.0
android 6.1.2

I think I'll try to get my hand on a fresh computer and see if it has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue. I have several plugins for the project, after added the device plugin recently I'm getting these issues:

```
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady.
Cancelled
```

After remove the device plugin these are gone and eveything back to normal.
I also suspect there might be bugs with the plugin itself.

```
Node version: v8.9.4
Cordova version: 8.0.0
cordova-plugin-device spec=^2.0.2
engine name=ios spec=~4.5.5
npm --v 5.7.1
```